# Assigning output from az artifacts universal download to variable

Tags: bash, jenkins, artifactory, azure-cli

I have a question. Is it possible to assign output from az aritfacts universal download to variable?
I have a Jenkins job where I have script in shell like this:

```
    az artifacts universal download \
      --organization "sampleorganization" \
      --project "sampleproject" \
      --scope project \
      --feed "sample-artifacts" \
      --name $PACKAGE \
      --version $VERSION \
      --debug \
      --path .
```

Then I would like transport the file to artifactory with this:

```
curl -v -u $ARTIFACTORY_USER:$ARTIFACTORY_PASS -X PUT https://artifactory.com/my/test/repo/my_test_file_{VERSION}
```

I ran the job but noticed that I passed to artifactory empty file. It created my_test_file_{VERSION} but it had 0 mb. As far as I understand I just created empty file with curl. So I would like to pass the output from az download to artifactory repo. Is it possible? How can I do this?

I understand that I need to assign file output to variable and pass it to the curl like:

$MyVariableToPass = az artifacts universal download output

And then pass this var to curl.

Is it possible? How can I pass files between Jenkins which triggers shell job to artifactory?
Also I am not using any plugin right now.

Please help.

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution is to use a VM as the agent of the Jenkins, and then install the Azure CLI inside the VM. You can run the task in that node. To set a variable with the value of the CLI command, for example, the output looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test_name",
  ....
}
```

Then you can set the variable like this:

```
name=$(az ...... --query name -o tsv)
```

This is in the Linux system. If it's in the Windows, you can set it like this:

```
$name = $(az ...... --query name -o tsv)
```

And as I know, the command to download the file won't output the content of the file. So if you want to set the content of the file as a variable, it's not suitable.